# Character encoding not declared when decrypting a PDF file stream from Crypto Stream

Tags: file, asp.net-core, security, encryption, filestream

I have the following method to encrypt files and save them to disk:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                byte[] key =
                {
                    0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
                    0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16
                };
                aes.Key = key;

                byte[] iv = aes.IV;
                fileStream.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length);

                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(fileStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter encryptWriter = new(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        await input.File.CopyToAsync(cryptoStream);                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And the following method to decrypt the file from disk and open in users browser:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                byte[] iv = new byte[aes.IV.Length];
                int numBytesToRead = aes.IV.Length;
                int numBytesRead = 0;
                while (numBytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    int n = fileStream.Read(iv, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);
                    if (n == 0) break;

                    numBytesRead += n;
                    numBytesToRead -= n;
                }

                byte[] key =
                {
                    0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
                    0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16
                };

                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new(fileStream, aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    // Desired option - not saving unenrypted to disk
                    var ms = new MemoryStream();
                    await cryptoStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
                    return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");

                    // TESTING PURPOSES ONLY - saving unenrypted to disk
                    //var outputStream = new FileStream("C:\\Files\\unencrypted.pdf", FileMode.Create);
                    //await cryptoStream.CopyToAsync(outputStream);                        
                    //return new FileStreamResult(outputStream, "application/pdf");        
                 
                }
            }
        }
```

I want for the user to be able to open the document in their browser, without saving the unencrypted back to disk.

However the above is resulting in the following on decrypt:

**The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.**

The code commented out saves the unencrypted file to disk and it can be opened from Windows explorer. However, still results in the same above error when run in the actual application.

Surely if the PDF in had the correct encoding, the unencrypted version should too, once the IV is removed from the start of the stream?

Comment: Was *anything* returned to the browser at all? If you google that message you'll see it's shown by the browser when the response is empty or has another serious problem, due to bugs in the server program. In this case you're using a `Stream` whose position is already at the end. `return new FileStreamResult(somestream, "application/pdf");` won't reset `Stream.Position` to 0. On the other hand, a MemoryStream is a wrapper over a `byte[]` buffer. You could return the buffer itself instead of the stream

Comment: Use the browser's Developer Tools to inspect the server's response. I suspect it's empty

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks very much for your reply. Simply adding ms.Position = 0; before returning the FileStreamResult has resolved the issue. Thank you